# Inherited QListWidgetItem and overloaded operator<. How to make sure that QListWidget sorts correctly?

Tags: qt, sorting, inheritance, operator-overloading

I made a new class named PageRangeListWidgetItem which inherits from QListWidgetItem

```
class PageRangeListWidgetItem : public QListWidgetItem
{
    ...
    private:
        int start, end;

        bool operator<(const PageRangeListWidgetItem &other) const {
            if (start == other.start)
                return end < other.end;
            return start < other.start;
        }
};
```

and these items are being added to a QListWidget through user input. The QListWidget contains only these PageRangeListWidgetItem's, so I hoped that by calling the sortItems() function of the QListWidget, that it would use the overloaded operator< to sort the items to my liking, but unfortunately it doesn't, it keeps on sorting the list as if it contained pure QListWidgetItems.

How can I change this behaviour? Do I have to create a custom QListWidget class or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<` function that is called by Qt's framework is

```
virtual bool operator<(const QListWidgetItem &other) const
```

The one you have defined does not match this function signature (`PageRangeListWidgetItem` instead of `QListWidgetItem`), and thus does not override the virtual function and doesn't get called.

You need to write a `<` function that takes in a `QListWidgetItem` and uses that object to sort rather than your custom object.

Comment: Thank you, but I guess that it is then impossible to compare the extra attributes "start, end" which define the PageRangeListWidgetItem, no? Or can it be something like  bool operator<(const QListWidgetItem &other) const {
      PageRangeListWidgetItem X = (PageRangeListWidgetItem) other;
            if (start == X.start)
                return end < X.end;
            return start < X.start;
        }  , is that even possible (as I am sure that all elements in the ListWidget actually /are/ of the type PageRangeListWidgetItem????

Comment: The way I solve this problem is usually to use the `setData()` and `data()` functions. This let's you store arbitrary data that's accessible from an object with the base class type.

Comment: Thank you, this is new to me, I will give it a try and post feedback :-)

Comment: Seems like it does the trick, thanks a billion! I hope you agree that I edit your answer a little bit and add the source code that I use now? Kind greetings, you are my hero of the day!

Comment: I created a class derived from QListWidgetItem, overriding the < operator using the "override" keyword. The overridden < operator never gets invoked by the sortItems() method. It seems that sortItems() always sorts by the text only and does not use the < operator.